# How do merge modules work and how can I get one for a version of Visual Studio I don't have installed?

Tags: windows-installer, merge-module

I have a vendor dependency that depends on VS 2005. According to Depends.exe it matches to:
`x86_microsoft.vc80.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.5592_none_cbf62b764709d1c9\MFC80.DLL`
`x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.5592_none_d09196c24426e2d4\MSVCR80.DLL`
`x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.5592_none_d09196c24426e2d4\MSVCP80.DLL`

Do I have to get a merge module with this exact version or can I use a later one? I can't find this version in the redistributables listed at:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/01/24/updated-vc-8-0-runtime-redistributable-packages-are-included-in-visual-studio-2005-sp1.aspx

In fact the versions seem to be lower so I'm not sure what constitutes a "later" one. I need to get this merge module without installing 2005 since I don't actually compile with 2005 myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the version of Visual C++ runtime and MFC from security update [MS11-025](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms11-025). Updated merge modules are available only as part of the Visual Studio 2005 SP1 security update. The redistributables themselves are available [separately](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26347).

Comment: Are you sure that's the right update? The MFC update redistributable provides `mfc80.dll.8.0.50727.6195` but I don't see 5592. So again, do I have to have the exact version or can I use a later one?

Comment: Generally, yes, you can use a later version.